# Is there a way to level up only once when I have XP for more than one level-up?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

A level-up only happens when you choose which stat to increase. Otherwise, you stay the same level. However, if more than one level-up is buffered, when you go to stat-up, you must level-up all at once. Is there a way to stat-up only as many times as one wishes and save buffered levelling for later? Being able to do so would allow training on levels-that-are-before-the-level-you're-supposed-to-be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the game collects all the XP and triggers all level ups when you enter the skilltree screen.

I personally have never heard of a mod that would allow that either

Comment: Perhaps not. I am, however, quite sure that this was the default in Oblivion, where you would level up once for every sleep cycle.

Comment: I actually remember it differently: in Oblivion once you are eligible for level up the level up progression literally stops: once you sleep the progression bar is empty again, making it possible to not reach the maximum level

Comment: I've done several consecutive sleep cycles quite a number of times just to level up, because I always forget to sleep. This is especially obvious in the beginning of the game, when you level up more often.

Comment: This may or may not have been a bug squished in a post-RTM patch, though.

Comment: Then I am mistaken. Haven't played Oblivion for a few years now and by the time I started Knights of The Nine I was already at max skill levels

Comment: I, on the other hand, started playing Oblivion around Skyrim's release and still regularly come back to it for a quick quest here and there. I'm still one mission away from finishing the main questline. ;-)